# Angular Material Datepicker design issue when opening calendar

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material2

I am having an issue when using Angular Material Datepicker and I can't seem to find the root problem of it. I couldn't think of a way to word this question. Whenever I open the calendar and I'm selecting the day, the overlay is too large and is past the boundaries of the box. Hopefully, this attached image can help:

[image: Datepicker Calendar Issue]

I have the following imports in the module the component is in:

```
import { MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatOptionModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MomentDateModule } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
```

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
 <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
 <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
 <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

The Datepicker is not in any div element that would change its styling. Right now, I'm only selecting a year and month. In the future, there are plans to select the day, as well, and that is when the issue arises.

Comment: may be some **css** are not loading properly can you please share your code in **stackblitz**

Comment: I'm sorry. I've tried, but it doesn't behave in Stackblitz like it does on my machine.

Comment: I have replicated your issue in **stackblitz**. can you please check?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have your custom `css` for `table` class like

```
table-layout: fixed;
width: 150%;
```

Angular date picker is also internally using the table structure.
so it override's the `css` of the angular material classes.

so in your custom `css` table exclude the class `'mat-calendar-table'` by using `:not` class.

check below `styles.css` file for your reference [check here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-qlzmwr?file=src/styles.css)

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it works. I assumed it had to do something with the table element. Thank you.