# Mat Date Picker overflows when opened

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-components, angular11

In my Angular project I use `mat date picker` in multiple places. Recently I started see this issue(not sure what caused it), mat date picker overflows when opened. I see this issue across the application not just at one place. Not sure how to describe it, attaching the screen shot for reference. I couldn't reproduce this in StackBlitz as this is specific to my application. I am using Angular and Material 11.1.2

**Update**: After digging further, I figured out `mat-calendar-table` class is actually crossing the boundaries and causes overflow

[image: Mat Date Picker Issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637322/angular-material-datepicker-design-issue-when-opening-calendar) adding `table-layout: fixed;` to table tag in **styles.scss** file fixed my issues

```
table
{
  table-layout: fixed !important;
  width: 100% !important; 
}
```

If you also use `mat-table` and you don't want mat-table layout to be fixed, add the following css to **styles.scss**

```
table
{
  table-layout: fixed !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.mat-table
{
  table-layout: auto !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through your global Styles, check if there is any global styling to `tr` or `td`, `td` especially.